# YouTube API does not play videos as expected

Tags: java, android, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I'm attempting to build a very simple video player using the Youtube API for Android. So far I have one video (which can be clicked and played) and two thumbnails below it - my problem is: I need to figure out how I can (correctly) assign different videos to each thumbnail - then play them.

I've attempted assign the thumbnails so using:

```
 public static final String VIDEO1_ID = "HNtBphqE_LA";
 public static final String VIDEO2_ID = "YWteQj_q3Ro";
 public static final String VIDEO3_ID = "Ak--L4bYly0";
```

But for some reason I get the correct thumbnail displayed and video played for both youTubeThumbnailLoader1 and youTubeThumbnailLoader2.

Any suggestions? I simply need to tweak/modify the code below to show unique videos/thumbnails (instead of the same one repeated multiple times as it is now) and play them.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EBeF.png)

Code:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);

        youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView)findViewById(R.id.youtubeplayerview);
        youTubePlayerView.initialize(API_KEY, this);

        youTubeThumbnailView1 = (YouTubeThumbnailView)findViewById(R.id.youtubethumbnailview1);
        youTubeThumbnailView1.initialize(API_KEY, this);

        youTubeThumbnailView2 = (YouTubeThumbnailView)findViewById(R.id.youtubethumbnailview2);
        youTubeThumbnailView2.initialize(API_KEY, this);


        youTubeThumbnailView1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
    if(youTubePlayer != null){
     youTubePlayer.play();
    }
   }});


    youTubeThumbnailView2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
if(youTubePlayer != null){
 youTubePlayer.play();
}
}});
}

 @Override
 public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider,
   YouTubeInitializationResult result) {

 }

 @Override
 public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,
   boolean wasRestored) {

  youTubePlayer = player;

  if (!wasRestored) {
        player.cueVideo(VIDEO_ID);
      }
 }

 @Override
 public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubeThumbnailView thumbnailView, 
   YouTubeInitializationResult error) {



 }

 @Override
 public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubeThumbnailView thumbnailView, 
   YouTubeThumbnailLoader thumbnailLoader) {



  youTubeThumbnailLoader1 = thumbnailLoader;
  thumbnailLoader.setOnThumbnailLoadedListener(new ThumbnailLoadedListener());

  youTubeThumbnailLoader1.setVideo(VIDEO1_ID);

  youTubeThumbnailLoader2 = thumbnailLoader;
  thumbnailLoader.setOnThumbnailLoadedListener(new ThumbnailLoadedListener());

  youTubeThumbnailLoader2.setVideo(VIDEO2_ID);



 }

 private final class ThumbnailLoadedListener implements
    YouTubeThumbnailLoader.OnThumbnailLoadedListener {

  @Override
  public void onThumbnailError(YouTubeThumbnailView arg0, ErrorReason arg1) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onThumbnailLoaded(YouTubeThumbnailView arg0, String arg1) {


  }

 }

}
```

P.S.

I think this may have to do with the fact I'm using youTubeThumbnailView1 and youTubeThumbnailView2 to create multiple thumbnails - however I have a feeling this might not be the correct way of doing so.

Comment: Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't set the right video for your thumbnails. There is no difference inside each thumbnailView clickListener!

try something like this in your onCreate

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home);

    youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView)findViewById(R.id.youtubeplayerview);
    youTubePlayerView.initialize(API_KEY, this);

    youTubeThumbnailView1 = (YouTubeThumbnailView)findViewById(R.id.youtubethumbnailview1);
    youTubeThumbnailView1.initialize(API_KEY, this);

    youTubeThumbnailView2 = (YouTubeThumbnailView)findViewById(R.id.youtubethumbnailview2);
    youTubeThumbnailView2.initialize(API_KEY, this);

    youTubeThumbnailView1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        if(youTubePlayer != null){
            youTubePlayer.loadVideo(VIDEO1_ID)
            youTubePlayer.play();
        }
    });

    youTubeThumbnailView2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        if(youTubePlayer != null){
            youTubePlayer.loadVideo(VIDEO2_ID)
            youTubePlayer.play();
        }
    });

}
```

Note: I see a lot of messy stuff in your code.

```
 @Override
 public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubeThumbnailView thumbnailView, 
   YouTubeThumbnailLoader thumbnailLoader) {

    youTubeThumbnailLoader1 = thumbnailLoader;
    thumbnailLoader.setOnThumbnailLoadedListener(new ThumbnailLoadedListener());

    youTubeThumbnailLoader1.setVideo(VIDEO1_ID);

    youTubeThumbnailLoader2 = thumbnailLoader;
    thumbnailLoader.setOnThumbnailLoadedListener(new ThumbnailLoadedListener());

    youTubeThumbnailLoader2.setVideo(VIDEO2_ID);
 }
```

This part shows that you lack basic understanding of programming. You could simply just write:

```
 @Override
 public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubeThumbnailView thumbnailView, 
   YouTubeThumbnailLoader thumbnailLoader) {

    thumbnailLoader.setOnThumbnailLoadedListener(new ThumbnailLoadedListener());
    thumbnailLoader.setVideo(VIDEO1_ID);
    thumbnailLoader.setVideo(VIDEO2_ID);

 }
```

which is clearly **not** what you intended. I guess you have to create different Listeners in your onCreate. Dont pass `this` inside the `initialze` method of your thumbnailViews and make the same switch I show you for the clickListener.

Also Try to nail down the problem you have and post only relating stuff.