# YouTubeThumbnailView Example

Tags: java, android, video, youtube, youtube-api

I'm attempting to use YouTubeThumbnailView to setup multiple thumbnails for a series of youtube videos. The problem is the same thumbnail is repeated over an over so I'm looking for an example of how this can be accomplished.

I've attempted to google search the issue but I've only been able to find examples with one thumbnail - I'm simply looking for an example of how to setup more than one (correctly).

### YouTubeThumbnailView Documentation:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubeThumbnailView

### Previous (unsuccessful) attempt:

[YouTube API does not play videos as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20103564/youtube-api-does-not-play-videos-as-expected-java-android)

Comment: I really need help with this - can someone please assist? : )

Answer (score 9):

I know your question was posted a long time ago, but for someone who will try to find solution later.

```
YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView;
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);

for(int i = 0 ; i < videos.length ; i++){
   final String videoID = videos[i];

   youTubeThumbnailView = new YouTubeThumbnailView(this);
   youTubeThumbnailView.setTag(videoID);
   youTubeThumbnailView.initialize(API_KEY, this);

   ll.addView(youTubeThumbnailView);
}
```

and for initialization

```
@Override
     public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubeThumbnailView thumbnailView, 
       YouTubeThumbnailLoader thumbnailLoader) {

      youTubeThumbnailLoader = thumbnailLoader;
      thumbnailLoader.setOnThumbnailLoadedListener(new ThumbnailLoadedListener());  

      youTubeThumbnailLoader.setVideo(thumbnailView.getTag().toString());     
     }
```

Comment: vokabakov, Can you please supply the layout and the full activity code ?

Comment: You can also add an 'onClick' to the thumbnail to get it to open the youtube link.

Answer (score 0):

Activity

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String API_KEY = "AIzTjlIUpkoRVgchvcCzW1Aebi0PqJU_ak";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);



    final YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView = (YouTubeThumbnailView) findViewById(R.id.youtubethumb_id);

    youTubeThumbnailView.setTag("UwTuL-PWxXw");

    youTubeThumbnailView.initialize(API_KEY, new YouTubeThumbnailView.OnInitializedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, final YouTubeThumbnailLoader youTubeThumbnailLoader) {

            youTubeThumbnailLoader.setVideo(youTubeThumbnailView.getTag().toString());

            youTubeThumbnailLoader.setOnThumbnailLoadedListener(new YouTubeThumbnailLoader.OnThumbnailLoadedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onThumbnailLoaded(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, String s) {
                    youTubeThumbnailLoader.release();
                }

                @Override
                public void onThumbnailError(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader.ErrorReason errorReason) {

                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

        }
    });

   }}
```

xml

```
<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView
    android:id="@+id/youtubethumb_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_150sdp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```